# How to open a URL in a window in "Maximized" mode using Crossrider appAPI.openURL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, window, crossrider

How to open a URL in a window in "Maximized" mode using Crossrider appAPI.openURL ?

Based on the Crossrider APIs located here,
[appAPI.openURL](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI) , you can open a URL in a new tab or in a window (with width and height) as below:

```
appAPI.openURL({
    url: "http://www.mysite.com",
    where: "window",
    height: 300,
    width: 500
});
```

How can you open the window in "Maximized" mode without using the width and height (but not in a new tab but in a new window)? I tried taking out the width and height options, but the window does not open in "Maximized" mode. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, opening a window in FullScreen mode is considered bad practice and is not recommended; hence, the Crossrider [appAPI.openURL](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-openURL) does not implement this feature. For more information, see [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) and search for **fullscreen** in the page.

Having said that, you can try approximating the feature by opening a window with its width and height properties set to the corresponding **window.screen** properties.

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: How can you open a window "maximized"? I actually meant "maximized" not "fullscreen"...my bad.

Comment: @Ali007 The solution I provided in the answer is in effect opening the browser maximized. I tested the following code in Chrome and it does the job, please test in other browsers: `appAPI.openURL({
  url: 'http://google.com',
  where: 'window',
  height: window.screen.height,
  width: window.screen.width
});`

Comment: I have tried that workaround approach before and it works fine. Just wanted to know if the appAPI.openURL has any built-in option that can open window truly "maximized" that I don't know about. Thanks for mentioning that though.

Comment: Similar to the FullScreen behavior, the opening maximized behavior is not supported, by all browsers (see [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#FAQ) and search for "How do I force a maximized window"). Who can argue with that? ;-)